# Using Perl to connect to Sybase db without Sybase Client in Windows

Tags: perl, installation, sybase, perl-module, failed-installation

I an trying to connect to Sybase with Perl.  i was trying to use DBD::Sybase to do that but when trying to install DBD::Sybase using perl Makefile.PL, I get the following error:

Please set SYBASE in CONFIG, or set the $SYBASE environment variable at Makefile.PL line 120,  line 44.

I believe I am getting this because i don't have Sybase client installed on my machine. Is there any way around this? I cannot download Sybase client due to enterprise restrictions. If anyone could point me to a source that distributes Sybase in compressed format, then maybe I could download that(I don't have permission to download .exe files).

Comment: if your company can't provide a sybase client, they clearly don't want you connecting to their databases... So Why would you need DBD::Sybase?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to work around via [ODBC](http://google.com/search?q=sybase+odbc).

Comment: Perhaps you can use freeTDS under DBD::Sybase to connect to Sybase.

Comment: @pavel well its a corporate policy not allowing ppl to download exe files. I can still connect using through java server. so i decided to do this a roun-about way. using java server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at greeted.org It seems that you can use sybperl with it.

Comment: Sorry, my ipad changed freetds.org to greeted.org.
http://www.freetds.org/ of course.